# make array of string to boolean

Tags: php, boolean

How can I make this into a boolean?

I tried this :

```
array('FALSE' => 'No', 'TRUE' => 'Yes')
```

I want the TRUE/FALSE to be treated as a boolean and not a string. How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

When you put values in quotes, they are treated as strings. Simply use the `true` and `false` boolean keywords, eg

```
array(
    false => 'No',
    true  => 'Yes'
)
```

Be mindful that PHP will auto-cast `true` to `1` and `false` to `0` in this case because

> The (array) key can either be an integer or a string

This won't stop you being able to use `$array[true]` or `$array[false]` though.

See http://php.net/manual/language.types.array.php

Comment: Shouldn't it be otherwise? true and false cannot be array indexes. I think Yes and No are supposed to be those.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Depends what the OP wants to do. This array could be used as part of a translation / i8n file for yes/no value output